# Animation of ListView Item

Tags: android, expandablelistview, listitem

I want to create a listview like below

[image]

[image]

[image]

please someone help me to achieve this?

Comment: No one can help you.At least a minimum effort is needed yourself.

Answer (score 3):

you can use expandable listview or expandable recyclerview.
inside expanded view, you can also add whole new view or fragment.

i got very good library for same.
https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

Comment: Thanx. Actually i was confuse about what should i use, listview or expandable listview.

Comment: Always well come bro